# Emitting event on close of other event (event chainning)

Tags: javascript, node.js, chaining, eventemitter

I have a software that does the following in sequence:

```
download text files from s3
reads the files
collect the data from files
```

The program is asynchronous-synchronous - each phase is asynchronous, but it heavily depends on the output of the previous phase, so i'm using Promises for build the chainning.

The problem of this architecture is that is using to much cpu since i'm spawning child processes in the extract and collect phase. So i decide to change to events:

How i'm doing:

I have 3 eventEmitters: downloadFile, extract, collect:

```
downloadfile.emit("copy", s3file);
downloadfile.on("error", callback);
downloadfile.on("close", (file) => {
 extract.emit("file", file);
 extract.on("error", callback);
 extract.on("close", (file) => {
   collect.emit("data", file.data);
   collect.on("error", callback);
   collect.on("close", (data) => {
      data is here... i can use without waiting all the other files.
   });
 });
});
```

But this isn't very readable... i prefer the Promise way:

```
Promise.resolve(options)
  .then(downloadFiles)
  .then(extract)
  .then(collect);
```

So i was thinking... is it possible to chain the events? I mean, the output of an event will be the input of other, just like the Promises? If so, how could i achieve that?

Comment: *"The problem of this architecture is that is using to much cpu, cause which phase will loop on the array of files"* That doesn't follow. Promises don't randomly burn CPU, it's what you're doing in the processing that burns CPU. That's not going to change switching to events instead; if it *seemed* to, you changed something else at the same time. Perhaps if you showed us what you were doing in the promises version, we could point out the problem.

Comment: Since they're event emitters you don't have to nest all of the callbacks. Everything below extract.emit should be able to be on the same level as downloadFile.emit and the same goes for everything below collect.emit. That's probably as nice as you're going to get on making it more readable. I agree with TJ though you should provide your promise snippet. I've done plenty of large file download with promises and without any cpu issues.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't TJ, this is a software of my job :/. And i agree with you, the Promise is not burning the CPU, but what i'm doing after the download it is. In every phase i need loop over the array of files and use the async.eachLimit to limit the asynchronous operations, this isn't good. In one phase i'm collecting the data using Regular Expressions, and in the other i'm spawning child processes. This i heavy, both operations depend on scripts that are writting in other languagues (that's why i'm spawning the processes)... if i do it with events, the improvements will be considerable.

Comment: Could you provide an example @Datise?